# Create time estimate based on user input time

Tags: python

I am trying to calculate time estimates based on a user input time in python. I have tried timedelta, timesplit. Essentially I want to take the start time provided by the user and calculate what time each task should be completed.

```
from datetime import time
rat = input("Enter times in HH:MM\n").split
for time in rat:
   hour, min = [int(i) for i in time.split(":")]
   print (hour,min)
par1 = time
par2 = par1+ datetime.timedelta(hours=1, minutes=30)
par3 = par2+(1.5/1440)
par4 = par3+(1.5/1440)
```

Comment: What isn't working and waht kind of output are you expecting? Also, don't use `time` as a variable name considering that you also imported `time`.

Comment: `rat = input("Enter times in HH:MM\n").split` You are not calling the `split` function.

Comment: I get an error when I run for t in rat that says the object is not iterable. I am expecting to add 1 hour and 30 minutes to the inputed time for par2 then par 3 would be 1 hour 30 minutes after that.